# How to remove parsley validation message?

Tags: parsley.js

If I don't want text to displayed if a required field is not entered. How would I do this? I wasn't able to find documentation on this.

I don't want the 'This value is required.' or custom message within data-required-message to be displayed.

I am fine with the field being highlighted if it is entered incorrectly. Is this possible?

Comment: Found documentation on this. If you use the data-parsley-errors-messages-disabled attribute then the validation messages will go

Answer (score 2):

According to Parsley Documentation in their version 2, they already supported this features, just add **"data-parsley-errors-messages-disabled"** attribute to the **<form>** tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add data-parsley-errors-messages-disabled to the field

from documentation:

Add parsley-success and parsley-error classes on field, but no error message.

Answer (score -2):

In the input set data-parsley-required="false"

Comment: This answer calls for an explanation and discussion of when it is appropriate to do so.

Answer (score -3):

You want to check validity of the field, but show no message. The way to customize the error message shown is using "data-parsley-error-message" , so the "hack" is to provide an empty custom message:

In the input set this `data-parsley-error-message=""`

Comment: This answer calls for an explanation and discussion of when it is appropriate to do so.

Comment: You want to check validity of the field, but show no message. The way to customize the error message shown is using "data-parsley-error-message" , so the "hack" is to provide an empty custom message. As more than a year has passed, and there are no "accepted" answers in the thread, at least, this code works. More correct solutions are welcome.

Comment: That's perfect - please edit your answer to include these details, it'll make it better.